# In Excel, I would like to find the last value in a column that is less than each cell in the column

Tags: excel-formula

For example, My values are 5, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 7.  I would like to find the last value that is less than each cell.  The last value less than 5 would be 4.  The last value less than 8 would be 7, etc.  I'm currently using this formula:

=LOOKUP(9.999999999999E+307,IF(B2:$B$4204

But I'm having no luck.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the last value in the list that is less than the value:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:$A$7)/($A$1:$A$7<A1),1))
```

[image]

---

If you only want to look at the values under the current value change to:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A1:$A$7)/($A1:$A$7<A1),1))
```

Comment: I was playing with match() and getting close, but that is nice.

Comment: That does it.  Thank you, sir.